# How to change content without reloading using only PHP

Tags: php, html, web

So i've been reading to a lot of articels about changing the content without reload/refresh the whole page.
But i wondering if there is a way to do these stuffs without using ajax/javascript.

I am still a beginner.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a **server-side** scripting language.

All the action happens *on the server*, before the page is ever even sent to you.

By the time the page arrives in your browser, the server has run through the whole script and then sent the page to you.

You cannot then ask the server to do anything more with the page because your current download of the page has left the server and is now sitting *in the browser* on your screen.